# Converting camera input to an RTMP stream for a live streaming function within an existing web application

Tags: web, video-streaming, rtmp, live-streaming

I need to be able to take the input video from a client side camera and convert it to an RTMP stream to be viewed live by other clients as part of a website application I am building. What libraries exist that could help facilitate this?

Comment: Asking for offsite resources on stackoverflow is considered off-topic. If you need to capture in the browser then the Wowza Media Server has a WebcamRecording example in the Examples folder (`fla` included, you don't need the entire media server just the example, get the demo). There are also a lot of git hub projects like https://github.com/AF83/webcam-streaming (older). For an RTMP server look at Nginx (basic version) + the nginx-rtmp-module (https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module).

Comment: Thank you for your help.